# Streamwriter Event like Close or finished?

Tags: c#, events, streamreader, streamwriter

I wanted to star a Streamreader directly after a Streamwriter finished its job.
This has to be like this, because the Streamreader is reading the file, which the Streamwriter wrote.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What programming language are you talking about?

Comment: And why would a streamwriter be closing, unless you told it to close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start typing. Write a class that derives from `StreamWriter` and overrides `Dispose`.

```
class StreamWriterThatDoesExtraStuffWhenClosed : StreamWriter
{
    public StreamWriterThatDoesExtraStuffWhenClosed(string s) : base(s) { }

    protected override void Dispose(bool f) {
        base.Dispose(f);
        ... do whatever you like here ...
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, and how can I start a function out of the main form in this class? Is that possible?

Comment: That sounds like an unrelated question.